# smallest integral divisor in OCaml

Tags: algorithm, recursion, ocaml

I want to get a smallest integral divisor of a given number n

```
    let rec smallest_divisor : int -> int
    =fun n -> let i = ref 2 if n mod !i = 0 then i else (i :!i+1; smallest_divisor(n))
```

What I mean above that code is first variable i is 2, and if (n mod i) is 0 then return i, else i+1 and repeat that function
I really have no idea how to get this

Comment: `i` is not a variable you may modify, you should rather consider it like a *constant value*, which got set at function call. Thus, in order to have something mutable, you must either use a `ref`, or have an auxiliary parameter to your function for `i`, which will be incremented for each recursive call to your function. See the answer below for inspiration (he uses an auxiliary function for recursion).

Answer (score 0):

For very large number it might be better to try testing only prime numbers. Your approach can work, but be aware that it might not be suitable for big numbers.

Another note: while writing recursive functions you should pay attention to the base case.

This is a minimal example that can achieve what you described, but keep in mind that it is not the best way to go about it:

```
let smallest_divisor n = 
    let rec aux n i = 
         if i > (n / 2) then n (* base case, should use sqrt here *) else 
               if (n mod i == 0) then i else aux n (i + 1) in
    aux n 2;;
```

Comment: Does a number 2 in the last line "in aux n 2;;" mean a first value of i ?

Comment: Yes. That's the first value of `i` passed to `aux` .